# migration apache commons cookiePolicy to cookieSpec of httpClient4.3

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I'm migrating httpClient 3.1 to 4.5.

The Orgignal code is:

```
httpGet.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
```

And I want to change it to:

```
requestConfigBuilder.setCookieSpec(????)
```

I couldn't find how should it be changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some of the cookie specs from `org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs`:

```
  RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT)
```

Check out the whole example:
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConfiguration.java